# In Mathematica, how to superpose two ListLinePlot?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, interpolation

I was using ListPlot to draw two smooth lines through some data points. But I want to superpose the plot.I learned that the method used by ListPlot for interpolation is to interpolate each coordinate as a function of the list index. So I can not simply plus two 
interpolations of my two points.

thanks,

jzm

Here is some text for copy/paste:

```
myPoints1 = {{1.4620657889458748`, 
335.2985577878116`}, {1.4620965802217518`, 
103.38351787529564`}, {1.4621942025270345`, 
62.5559208248015`}, {1.462354896492246`, 
45.566589506360216`}, {1.4625751467402768`, 
36.264281440327565`}, {1.4628516301983985`, 
30.399003865053114`}, {1.4631812807492346`, 
26.367460111951058`}, {1.4635611902991474`, 
23.429554855802188`}, {1.4639886111585874`, 
21.195443300677702`}, {1.464460983399038`, 
19.440829611123966`}, {1.4649759015994719`, 
18.02777886500251`}, {1.4655311109490736`, 
16.86675689819105`}, {1.466124470097565`, 
15.896899417397284`}, {1.4667539758770534`, 
15.075547889029616`}, {1.467417728656181`, 
14.37183869811537`}, {1.468113935160521`, 
13.76291072113658`}, {1.4688409098827062`, 
13.231534377122449`}, {1.4695970390339186`, 
12.764290193109172`}, {1.4703808152150737`, 
12.350655500316538`}, {1.47119080820051`, 
11.982259112096562`}, {1.4720256766729714`, 
11.652466731657922`}, {1.4728841551349938`, 
11.35608813384227`}, {1.4737650210799367`, 
11.088805023428025`}, {1.4746670942175184`, 
10.846730689594123`}, {1.4755892711659102`, 
10.626599181057326`}, {1.4765305432312286`, 
10.425844517518913`}, {1.4774899140433866`, 
10.242189544437958`}, {1.4784664768294848`, 
10.07388845283117`}, {1.4794593535682306`, 
9.91948469998374`}, {1.480467656424019`, 
9.777491405153027`}, {1.4814906043125302`, 
9.646805534544441`}, {1.4825273964568986`, 
9.526291139015447`}, {1.4835772786981303`, 
9.414764726544572`}, {1.4846395968104766`, 
9.311395888282872`}, {1.4857136927436698`, 
9.215545785306015`}, {1.4867989654798728`, 
9.12678547130485`}, {1.487894785812934`, 
9.0445918653539`}, {1.489000547636927`, 
8.968341543739935`}, {1.49011571024499`, 
7.71616343700933`}, {1.4912397307928495`, 
4.4771368717931965`}, {1.4930948425223702`, 
2.7599903709003706`}, {1.4972705714803425`, 2.137733395169292`}};
```

myPoints2 = {{1.9550995254889463`, 
    0.7164793699550908`}, {1.9391287471262355`, 
    0.41710931241140287`}, {1.9139528821159193`, 
    0.3490726623599497`}, {1.884617534719042`, 
    0.3308820126668058`}, {1.8540123750258504`, 
    0.33265450551933234`}, {1.8237456098779754`, 
    0.3452794413751484`}, {1.7946805323610866`, 
    0.36513934480358856`}, {1.7672498634600862`, 
    0.3905924543768967`}, {1.7416378319498413`, 
    0.42085584504202456`}, {1.717886011205134`, 
    0.45557423825820337`}, {1.6959554065943552`, 
    0.49463019895914645`}, {1.675763216373194`, 
    0.5380524422510392`}, {1.6572047192352064`, 
    0.5859687470445493`}, {1.6401662975943239`, 
    0.6385812315738714`}, {1.6245331447101943`, 
    0.6961532977719818`}, {1.6101937002933333`, 
    0.7590036122922289`}, {1.5970420916568349`, 
    0.8275045669571167`}, {1.5849793700525658`, 
    0.9020832266507519`}, {1.5739139593253322`, 
    0.9832255360102758`}, {1.5637616875683809`, 
    1.071482155332956`}, {1.5544455489784297`, 
    1.1674755467368436`}, {1.5458952859916812`, 
    1.2719109855898907`}, {1.538046945587126`, 
    1.3855881585132812`}, {1.5308423787211705`, 
    1.5094157124835617`}, {1.5242287288899015`, 
    1.6444321762294256`}, {1.5181579889629853`, 
    1.7918272163885938`}, {1.512586535548833`, 
    1.952969437543702`}, {1.5074747129386745`, 
    2.1294427702228105`}, {1.5027864632086367`, 
    2.3230885849762424`}, {1.4984889655043911`, 
    2.536061738604728`}, {1.4945523307439923`, 
    2.7708992557015053`}, {1.4909493139037207`, 
    3.0306073328297867`}, {1.4876550515968234`, 
    3.3187795649748657`}, {1.4846468371914137`, 
    3.6397480437107252`}, {1.481903916697491`, 
    3.9987774524193394`}, {1.4794072959177726`, 
    4.4023273698572325`}, {1.4771395719585305`, 
    4.858408392792459`}, {1.4750847772800355`, 
    5.37708563628973`}, {1.4732282431253443`, 
    5.971204815109932`}, {1.4715564902918326`, 
    6.657415608955233`}, {1.4700571242943155`, 
    7.457674059555506`}, {1.4687187279247118`, 
    8.40154880208839`}, {1.4675307832019475`, 
    9.529729255387132`}, {1.4664835796976867`, 
    10.899794007715421`}, {1.46556811155878`, 
    12.596323274840168`}, {1.4647760611386595`, 
    14.748618559900901`}, {1.4640997339059703`, 
    17.564564972128032`}, {1.463531979901696`, 
    21.401490423013954`}, {1.4630661880201312`, 
    26.92897502098747`}, {1.462696204020183`, 
    35.566591773864054`}, {1.4624163023794263`, 
    50.94289950596402`}, {1.462221186527755`, 
    85.91265697099175`}, {1.4621058905589708`, 
    243.1565306412274`}, {1.4620657889458748`, 335.2985577878116`}};

what I want is not

```
Show[ListPlot[myPoints1, Joined -> True, Mesh -> Full], 
     ListPlot[myPoints2, Joined -> True, Mesh -> Full]]
```

don't know how to get the plot of the value's superpostion of the two plot.Please help!:)
The meaning of "superpostion" is to get the plus of the value of the two curves at every x-axis.

Comment: try to explain better the result you expect, this "values superpositon" is not clear at all.

Comment: Sorry not interpret my question clearly. My hope is to get the plus of the value of the two curves at every x-axis. I don't know if I express the question more clearly this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want something like this in order to "plus" your lines.

```
it1 = Interpolation[myPoints1];
it2 = Interpolation[myPoints2];
t1 = Table[it1[i], {i, 1.467, 1.497, 0.001}];
t2 = Table[it2[i], {i, 1.467, 1.497, 0.001}];
t3 = Transpose[{Range[1.467, 1.497, 0.001], t1 + t2}];
ListPlot[{myPoints1, myPoints2, t3}, Joined -> True,
 PlotRange -> {{1.467, 1.497}, {0, 30}}, PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very  much！Sorry not interpret my question clearly. Sometimes the range of "i" is not alway the same. For example, Min[myPoint1]may be 1, Min[myPoint2]may be 1.467. Do I have to separate the domain of data into several parts?

Comment: You only need a common range for the sum, `t1 + t2`

Comment: I tried these codes:
`it1 = Interpolation[myPoints1];
it2 = Interpolation[myPoints2];
t1 = Table[it1[i], {i, 1.467, 1.497, 0.001}];
t2 = Table[it2[i], {i, 1.467, 1.497, 0.001}];
t22 = Table[it2[i], {i, 1.497, 1.9, 0.001}];
t222 = Transpose[{Range[1.497, 1.9, 0.001], t22}];
t3 = Transpose[{Range[1.467, 1.497, 0.001], t1 + t2}];
ListPlot[t3]
ListPlot[t222]
ListLinePlot[Union[t3, t222], PlotRange -> All]

`


I don't know is this method good enough to get the whole plot of my points?

Comment: Looks ok, except `Union[t3, t222]` has two points at x = 1.497.  Could do `ListLinePlot[Join[t3, Rest@t222], PlotRange -> All]`